# How do I get my text back above and under my image?

Tags: css, html, center

Hello I'm new to html & css and I have a question. I'm using the following code to set some images with text above and under it as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/thespacebean/xGqDE/

But now i'm trying to re-use that code in another box but the text isn't where it needs to be. here a use another type of box:

css:

```
#content{
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Kleding</h2>
    <div id="navbanner">
    <div id="nav2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="Babynav">Baby</a></li>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="Peuternav">Peuter</a></li>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="Kleuternav">Kleuter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="img">
      <img src="../images/winkelwagen.jpg">
    </div>
    <h3>Baby</h3>
    <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"> Pika deken</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/baby1.jpg" /></a>
        €20
    </div>
    <div class="section">

        <a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg" /></a>
        €140
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html">Bussines girl</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/girl2.jpg" /></a>
        €250
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <a href="../html/kleding.html">Summer</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/girl1.jpg" /></a>
        €99.99
    </div>
</div>
```

And thats why everything is floating left. Can someone get my images and the text under and above centerd without moving the navbar and Baby title? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

the fiddle example has

```
text-align: center;
```

in the CSS put you don't appear to have this in your CSS so the text will be on the left;

Comment: Great now the text i back where it belongs. But now i need to center the whole so text and images.

Comment: Put a element around your entire content block and give it a width (say 960px) then a margin:auto. This will centre your content div inside the outer element.